# How do I retrieve the @html.editorfor's value in asp.net MVC?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I need to retrieve the value of the `startdate` so that I can combine the `startdate` with the start time and get the datetime. How do I retrieve the data or the value of the `@html.EditorFor`?

I have already tried using jQuery to get the data but I can't find the way to link the jQuery and the values inside the `@{}` up.

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.StartDate, new { htmlAttributes = new { 
@class = "form-control border-input", @type = "date", id = "modelId" } 
})
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.StartDate, "", new { @class = 
"text-danger" })
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.StartTime, new { htmlAttributes = new { 
@class = "form-control border-input", @type = "time", id = "modelId2" } })
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.StartTime, "", new { @class = 
"text-danger" })
```

I expect that I can combine the date and time together

Comment: Not sure what you're asking but `$('#StartDate').val()` will give you the value.

Comment: `$('#StartDate').val()` should get the date string. The problem is you need to convert it as JS `Date` object before processing in client-side.

Comment: Do you want to combine start date and start time and current time?

Comment: I want to combine my start date and start time and form it into the startdatetime which will then go into my database

Comment: You'll need to clarify your question. The above code doesn't ask for any time, just a date from the user. One can _assume_ you just need some date/time stamp (not provided by the user)?

Comment: do you want to combine into controller or  view?

Comment: I assume you're posting this view back to the controller. In that case you can just combine the two in the controller.